# Exception: opencv imshow assertion failed

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, imshow

This question is related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404342/multidimensional-cvmat-initialization-and-display). Basically, I'm getting the following exception while using cv::imshow("window", mat):

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (p[-1] <=2) in cv::MatSize::operator(), file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core/mat.inl.hpp, line 1097

It doesn't make sense: I tried imshow'ing both a 3D cv::Mat file (CV_32F), as well as tried to convert it to a CV_8U format and tried displaying that. Both times it gave the same error.

The relevant code snippets:

```
cv::Mat depthMat( height, width, CV_8UC1 );
```

depthMat contains the depth map.

Then I declare normMat which will contain surface normal at each depth pixel

```
int sizes[3] = { height, width, 3 };
cv::Mat normMat(3, sizes, CV_32F, cv::Scalar::all(0));

//for loop
//normal calculation
normMat.at<float>(i, j, 0) = fVec3[0];
normMat.at<float>(i, j, 1) = fVec3[1];
normMat.at<float>(i, j, 2) = fVec3[2];

//end for loop
```

Then I try to display this surface normal image as an RGB image, normalized between 0 and 255 (I also tried between 1 and 0 as given in the documentation and that didn't work either).

```
cv::Mat normColorMap(height, width, CV_8UC3);

normMat.convertTo(normColorMap, CV_8U, 0, 255);

cv::namedWindow("Normals");
cv::imshow("Normals", normColorMap);
```

If I try to imshow normMat I get the same error. Basically, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since the convertTo function did not throw any errors. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The code changed a bit but following is my nested for loop:

```
for (int i = 5; i < height; i++){
                for (int j = 5; j < width-5; j++){

                cv::Point3f p1(i, j, (float)depthMat.at<unsigned char>(i, j));
                cv::Point3f p2(i - 5, j, (float)depthMat.at<unsigned char>(i - 5, j));
                cv::Point3f p3(i, j + 5, (float)depthMat.at<unsigned char>(i, j + 5));

                //compute vector in vertical and horizontal direction
                    float fVec1[3];
                    float fVec2[3];
                    float fVec3[3];

                    fVec1[0] = p2.x - p1.x;
                    fVec1[1] = p2.y - p1.y;
                    fVec1[2] = p2.z - p1.z;

                    fVec2[0] = p3.x - p1.x;
                    fVec2[1] = p3.y - p1.y;
                    fVec2[2] = p3.z - p1.z;

                //Computer the cross product of these 2 vectors in the image plane  
                    fVec3[0] = (fVec1[1] * fVec2[2]) - (fVec1[2] * fVec2[1]);
                    fVec3[1] = (fVec1[2] * fVec2[0]) - (fVec1[0] * fVec2[2]);
                    fVec3[2] = (fVec1[0] * fVec2[1]) - (fVec1[1] * fVec2[0]);

                    //Normalize the surface normal vector (fVec3)
                    float flen = sqrt(fVec3[0] * fVec3[0] + fVec3[1] * fVec3[1] + fVec3[2] * fVec3[2]);
                    fVec3[0] = fVec3[0] / flen;
                    fVec3[1] = fVec3[1] / flen;
                    fVec3[2] = fVec3[2] / flen;



                    normMat.at<float>(i, j, 0) = fVec3[0];
                    normMat.at<float>(i, j, 1) = fVec3[1];
                    normMat.at<float>(i, j, 2) = fVec3[2];



            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post your nested loop parameters too?

Comment: Done. Please see above

Comment: imshow() can only handle 2d images. (also convertTo() only changes the type of a single element, not the channels.)  all in all, i'd rather avoid 3d Mat's in opencv, they're just not 'natural' (and badly supported)

Comment: use a Mat(h, w, CV_32FC3) instead.